# $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof for inverse function

Tags: real-analysis

I have been struggling to prove the following claim without appealing any other theorem, except the definition of continuity. If any one give a step by step argument for it, that would be great. Many thanks!

> Let $f$ be strictly increasing function on $[a,b]$. If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $f^{-1}$ is continuous on $[f(a),f(b)]$.

Comment: Did you prove that strictly increasing functions are injective?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: Yes I proved that part, but couldn't figure out the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show $f^{-1}(x)$ is continuous at $y_0\in [f(a),f(b)]$, we assume $y_0=f(x_0)$ for some $x_0\in [a,b]$(note this $x_0$ is unique). By definition, for any $\epsilon>0$, we need to find a $\delta>0$ such that
$$
|f^{-1}(y)-f^{-1}(y_0)|<\epsilon\quad \text{when } |y-y_0|<\delta
$$

Define $\delta:=\min\{f(x_0+\epsilon)-f(x_0),f(x_0)-f(x_0-\epsilon)\}$. If $x_0+\epsilon>b$, use $f(b)$ instead;if $x_0-\epsilon<a$, use $f(a)$ instead. Moreover, if $y_0=f(a)\ or\ f(b)$, then $\delta=f(a+\epsilon)-f(a)\ or\ f(b)-f(b-\epsilon)$. Now I will leave it to you that this $\delta$ is what we desired for.

Note: It seems I didn't use the continuity of $f(x)$, but what we need is $f(x)$ should be surjective, or rather, $f^{-1}(x)$ is defined everywhere on $[f(a),f(b)]$

Comment: +1: Nice observation that continuity is required for surjectivity in this situation.